# Can I say "thus much can be said that"?

Tags: word-choice

Thus much can be said that apart from geographical remoteness and the early formation of a highly centralized government, the commandments functioning as the moral core of the social and political order and believed universally by the people, must also plays a crucial role in development of Chinese civilization. (self-made)

Can "thus much" be used this way together with "that"? I know we normally say "it can be said that". But I want to emphasize that I want to say much, but it is the most I can say now, since "it is.." is too weak, I use this structure now, what do you think of it?

Comment: No, this sounds quite awkward and wrong, but I am not sure of the exact rule it breaks. Can you change "much" to "it?"

Comment: Why complicate the specific (trivial) point being queried with such an appalling example of turgid prose? Remove a few syntactically irrelevant clauses, and it's just ***Thus much can be said that the commandments** [are] **crucial***. Which is obviously drivel.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you intend *thus* to be understood.

- If you mean *thus* in the sense of *consequently*, you would do well to put a comma after it, so it will not be taken to collocate with *much*.

  > Thus, much can be said ...
- If what you are asking about is the collocation *thus much* meaning “so much”  or “this much”, I urge you not use it; it is a pseudo-erudite colloquialism which is not well regarded in formal writing. I suggest you say *This much* or perhaps even *Only this much*

  > This much can be said ...

If you intend both, I suggest this:

> Thus, only this much can be said ...

In either case, I think you would do well to set a colon after the initial clause. If you do so, you may omit the *that*:

> (Thus) only this much can be said: apart from ...

There are more awkwardnesses and ambiguities in what follows; but your question does not address those.

ADDED:
It occurs to me that if you want to leave yourself an opening for saying more at some later point, *at least* instead of *only* might be appropriate:

> Thus at least this much can be said: ...

Or even, for a full academic plonk:

> Thus, at least this much can be confidently asserted: ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix it so:

> Thus much can be said *about the fact* that, apart from geographical remoteness and the early formation of a highly centralized government, the commandments, functioning as the moral core of the social and political order and believed universally by the people, must also *have played* a crucial role in *the* development of Chinese civilization.

Though to be honest I think this sentence is rather awkward.

Comment: This only makes sense if it refers to a previous paragraph, which may be true but is not indicated.

Answer (score 0):

*Thus much* was never right.  You could try "This much can be said: that as well as geographical remoteness...", and you would probably get away with replacing the colon with a comma, unless your audience is fastidious (like the ELU crowd, for example).
Even "So much can be said: that as well as..." would be possible, though rather rarefied.

Additionally, *apart from* is both ugly and imprecise here: do you mean *as well as, besides* or *despite*? And *plays* is certainly the wrong tense; I think that should be *have played*.